# How to scroll an image vertically using ffmpeg and detect the end-of-image (EOI) at same time?

Tags: image, video, scroll, ffmpeg, vertical-scrolling

I need to scroll an image vertically, from the top of the image to the bottom of the image, and then stop creating the output video as soon as the last bottom bit of the image scrolls off the top of the screen.

Comment: Since this was most recently answered, a scroll filter was added to ffmpeg, but I can't seem to figure out how for example to set `v` in this command (found [over here](https://twitter.com/FFmpeg/status/1180179571456372737)) such that it scrolls an image once per second (adapting the command for vertical scroll): `ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -i input.png -vf "scroll=v=0.001,crop=640:360:0:ih,format=yuv420p" -preset veryslow -crf 18 -t 10 output.mp4` -- I figured out it will be 0.03333 for an image cropped at its own height, but if it's a taller image than the crop area, that changes. ?

Comment: @AlexHall interesting. Did you figure it out, and how does this scroll option compare in functionality with other options listed here, including runtime?

Comment: I have not figured it out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To do this in one command, use

`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=s=1920x1080 -loop 1 -t 0.08 -i "input.png" -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1920:-2,setpts=if(eq(N,0),0,1+1/0.02/TB),fps=25[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=y=-'t*h*0.02':eof_action=endall[v]" -map "[v]" output.mp4`

Note, that in some shells (e.g. **Bash**) commas need to be escaped:

`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=s=1920x1080 -loop 1 -t 0.08 -i "input.png" -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1920:-2,setpts=if(eq(N\,0)\,0\,1+1/0.02/TB),fps=25[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=y=-'t*h*0.02':eof_action=endall[v]" -map "[v]" output.mp4`

The `-t` is added for the image so that we have a stream with 2 frames. (`25 fps x 0.08 = 2`). The setpts sets the timestamp for the 2nd frame to the inverse of the scroll rate, which represents a fraction of the height. The fps filter fiils in the timestamp gaps with cloned frames.

The overlay is told to stop when the image input has finished.

Comment: Thank you. I get an error;
[Parsed_setpts_1 @ 0x55b3c88ebd40] [Eval @ 0x7ffcb0ec3bc0] Missing ')' or too many args in 'eq(N'
[Parsed_setpts_1 @ 0x55b3c88ebd40] Error while parsing expression 'if(eq(N'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x55b3c88e7fc0] Error initializing filter 'setpts' with args 'if(eq(N'
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument

Comment: Looks like your shell needs you to escape the commas within expressions, so `if(eq(N,0),0,1+1/0.02/TB)` --> `if(eq(N\,0)\,0\,1+1/0.02/TB)`

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thank you very much. This is using bash. It works perfectly! Added the command to the answer too for handy reference. God bless

Comment: side question - how to insert a small 2 second pause before the image starts scrolling?

Comment: Insert this setpts after the overlay, `setpts=if(eq(N\,0)\,0\,PTS+2/TB)`

Comment: you rock. Thank you!

Comment: For reference with 2 second pause at start; `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=s=1920x1080 -loop 1 -t 0.08 -i "6-answer9.png" -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1920:-2,setpts=if(eq(N\,0)\,0\,1+1/0.02/TB),fps=25[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=y=-'t*h*0.02':eof_action=endall,setpts=if(eq(N\,0)\,0\,PTS+2/TB)[v]" -map "[v]" output.mp4`

Comment: Btw, to make the background white when the scroll is in it's final stages, use; `color=s=1920x1080:color=0xffffff` instead.

Comment: Hey, your solution is perfect, however i'm quite a noob at handling ffmpeg and has some questions :
1) how do you increase fps ? I tried settings fps=50 and -t 0.04 so i can keep same frame ratio you used but it fail.
2) how should i proceed to add a 1 second pause at beginning and end of the video ? thanks for all your help.

Comment: There is a two second pause at the start, easy to change to one second. I expect pause at end to be similar. Not sure on FPS, have a look at ffmpeg documentation.

Comment: This is great! How can I make it stop immedately when the bottom image is at the bottom of the video?

Comment: @eivindml did you fin solution?

Comment: @RadicalEdward Unfortunately haven't figured it out.

Comment: @eivindml Found the solution, I will add the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution I found;

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=s=1920x1080 -loop 1 -i "input.png" -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1920:-2[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=y=-'t*h*0.02'[v]" -map "[v]" -t 00:03:00 output.mp4
```

Note that the scroll rate is 0.02. Set it lower, for example 0.01 to scroll slower, or higher - for example 0.03, to scroll faster.

Note that I passed a maximum time of 3 minutes to the command. This time, regrettably, needs to be larger then any image scroll output could ever take in your particular setup.

For reference, a 1920x7043 pixels image takes 49.88 seconds. You can get the height of an image programmatically using;

```
file input.png | sed 's|.*1920 x \([0-9]\+\).*|\1|'
output: 7043
```

If someone has a better way of "detecting the end of the image scroll - i.e. the last line/bottom of the image scrolling off the top of the screen" and the ability to scale the time/duration based on that - then that would be very handy.

For the moment this is the best solution I have; scan the output of the last ffmpeg command above for something like;

```
[blackdetect @ 0x559298835480] black_start:49.88
```

For example, using this command;

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -vf blackdetect=d=0.1:pix_th=.1 -f rawvideo -y /dev/null 2>&1 | grep -o "black_start:[\.0-9]\+ "
output: black_start:49.88
```

And crop accordingly;

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -t 49.88 -c copy finaloutput.mp4
vlc finaloutput.mp4  # Assuming you have vlc installed
```

Comment: Another way to possibly fix this is by somehow calculating the exact number of seconds/frames or similar needed inside the ffmpeg command and terminating after that. I am unsure if ffmpeg supports such (complex) syntax. Ideas welcome.

Comment: If you scroll at rate X% pf height, then time for image bottom to scroll past the top is 1/X seconds, if you start from image initially positioned at y=0.

Comment: @Roel Another method to get height: `ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=height -of csv=p=0 input.png`

Comment: @Gyan any way to do this programmatically in ffmpeg?

Comment: @Roel Added answer.